# FPGA ethernet pass through works one way but not the other

Tags: fpga, ethernet

[image]I am using 2 triple speed IP cores at 1Gig and using them as a pass through between 2 PHYs, one being strapped RGMII to copper and the other being strapped RGMII to 1000-BaseX.  I am using scapy to send UPD packets to test the pass through, and when I send from the fiber and out the copper I am able to view the UDP packets correctly on another system using wireshark.  When I try to send in reverse from copper to fiber, I do not get anything.

Using the signal debugger tool on my IDE, I am able to see the internal data signals for each direction.  The fiber to copper one looks as expected, and I am able to match the packet on wireshark to the packet that I read in the debugger.  When I do the same for the copper to fiber pass through, the signal debugger sees either nothing, or a jumbled mess of seemingly random data.  Obviously it is getting corrupted somewhere between where I read it and the source, but I am a little stuck.  I have tried reading the RGMII signals directly, but I don't really understand the encoding scheme, but they did not match, if that means anything.

I think I can safely say that both of the PHYs and MACs are configured correctly, as I don't think I would see any pass through from one side.  I am thinking this is more of a PCB/timing issue but I'm not sure.  I am sending UDP with the same script on the same machine for both.

Comment: Your question looks broad. You should put a block diagram of the whole setup. So that the community will get clarity of what you tried.

Comment: Sure, I added one to the post.  Hopefully this makes things more clear